# What is the current atmospheric concentration of $\small\sf{CO_2}$ in the atmosphere in atm (or bar)?

Tags: atmosphere, climate, co2, carbon, air

For some reason, I can only find the answer in ppm and I don’t know how to do this conversion.

Answer (score 3):

What I think you are asking for is the [partial pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_pressure) of carbon dioxide in the atmosphere.

The partial pressure of carbon dioxide can be determined, where,

$P_{CO_2} \ = \ x_{CO_2}\cdot P_{atm}$

One mole of any substance is equal to exactly 6.022⋅10<sup>23</sup> molecules of that substance (Avogadro's number, $N_A$).

The number of moles of carbon dioxide is,

$Moles\ of\ CO_2 \ = \ Number\ of\ molecules\ of\ CO_2 \cdot N_A$

If the atmosphere has a carbon dioxide concentration of 400 ppm, then

$n_{CO_2}\ = \ \frac{400}{1\ 000\ 000} \cdot N_A \ = \ 0.0004 \cdot N_A$

Thus, the partial pressure of carbon dioxide in the atmosphere will be,

$P_{CO_2} \ = 0.0004 \cdot 101\ 325 \ = \ 40.53 \ Pa \ = 0.0004 \ atm \ = \ 0.304 \ mmHg$

Answer (score 3):

Not nearly so elegant as @fred answer: 400 ppm = 0.04% , then CO 2 is 0,04 % or 0.0004 atm.

Comment: More elegant :)